# How to position the paper's authors' addresses on the front page (maketitle)?

Tags: titles

When I use the following code for the title page of a paper (please see below), the authors' addresses and emails appear on the last page of the paper. However I need them to appear on the first-title page (after the authors' names before the abstract). How can I do this?

```
\documentclass [reqno, 12pt ]{amsart}
...
\begin{document}

\title[paper]{Nice paper}

\author{Me}
\address{University}
\email{mmm@lala.com}
\thanks{.}
\author{my friend}
\address{Institute}
\email{kkk@lala.edu}
\thanks{.}

\date{\today}
\keywords{XXX }

\begin{abstract}
Lalala
\end{abstract}

\maketitle
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! You can give a try at the `titling` package (not sure it is compatible with `amsart`).

Comment: Related: [how do i put address between author's name and abstract in amsart?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/249052)

Answer (score 1):

changing the positioning of addresses in `amsart` is nontrivial.

here i have adapted the code used for an existing journal that has a
style similar to what has been requested.  the result is not perfect;
for one author, the address is placed on a separate line, but for more
than one author, the addresses are strung out after the associated
author name.  i haven't analyzed this sufficiently to determine how
long it would take to change robustly, but i have run out of time.

i hope this is useful.

```
\documentclass[reqno,12pt]{amsart}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\author}[2][]{%
  \def\@tempa{#1}
  \ifx\@empty\authors
    \ifx\@tempa\@empty
      \gdef\shortauthors{#2}%
    \else
      \gdef\shortauthors{#1}%
    \fi
    \gdef\authors{\author{#2}}%
  \else
    \ifx\@tempa\@empty
      \g@addto@macro\shortauthors{\and#2}%
    \else
      \g@addto@macro\shortauthors{\and#1}%
    \fi
    \g@addto@macro\authors{\and\author{#2}}%
  \fi
}
\renewcommand{\address}[2][]{\g@addto@macro\authors{\address{#1}{#2}}}
\def\@setauthors{%
  \begin{center}%
    \footnotesize
    \vspace{20pt}
    \let\and\@empty
    \def\author##1{\advance\@tempcnta\@ne}%
    \def\address##1##2{\advance\@tempcntb\@ne}%
    \@tempcnta=\z@  \@tempcntb=\z@
    \authors
    \ifnum\@tempcnta>\@ne \ifnum\@tempcntb=\@ne
        \oneaddress
      \else
        \sepaddresses
      \fi
    \else
      \oneaddress
    \fi
  \end{center}%
}
\def\oneaddress{%
  \begingroup
  \let\author\@iden \let\address\@gobbletwo
  \renewcommand{\andify}{%
    \nxandlist{\unskip, }{\unskip{} and~}{\unskip, and~}}%
  \uppercasenonmath\authors
  \andify\authors
  \authors
  \endgroup
  \begingroup \let\and\relax \let\author\@gobble
  \def\address##1##2{\unskip\\[10pt] \itshape##2}%
  \authors
  \endgroup
}
\def\sepaddresses{%
  \begingroup
    \baselineskip10\p@\relax
    \def\address##1##2{ ({\itshape##2}\/)}
    \def\author##1{\def\temp{##1}\leavevmode\uppercasenonmath\temp\temp}%
    \nxandlist
      {,\\[\baselineskip]}
      {\\[\baselineskip] \textsc{\lowercase{and}}\\[\baselineskip]}
      {,\\[\baselineskip]\textsc{\lowercase{and}}\\[\baselineskip]}
      \authors % macro to operate on
    \authors
  \endgroup
}
\def\maketitle{\par
  \@topnum\z@
  \@setcopyright
  \thispagestyle{firstpage}%
  \uppercasenonmath\shorttitle
  \ifx\@empty\shortauthors \let\shortauthors\shorttitle
  \else
    \newcommand{\@xuppercasenonmath}[1]{\toks@\@emptytoks
      \@xp\@skipmath\@xp\@empty##1$$%
      \edef##1{\@nx\protect\@nx\@upprep\the\toks@}}%
    \@xuppercasenonmath\shortauthors
    \def\@@and{AND}
    \renewcommand{\andify}{%
      \nxandlist{\unskip, }{\unskip{ }\@@and{ }}{\unskip, \@@and{ }}}%
    \andify\shortauthors
  \fi
  \@maketitle@hook
  \begingroup
  \@maketitle
  \endgroup
  \c@footnote\z@
  \@cleartopmattertags
}
\def\@maketitle{%
  \normalfont\normalsize
  \let\@makefntext\noindent
  \@adminfootnotes
  \ifx\@empty\addresses\else \@footnotetext{\@setotheraddresses}\fi
  \global\topskip68\p@\relax
  \@settitle
  \ifx\@empty\authors \else \@setauthors \fi
  \ifx\@empty\@dedicatory
  \else
    \baselineskip26\p@
    \vtop{\centering{\footnotesize\itshape\@dedicatory\@@par}%
      \global\dimen@i\prevdepth}\prevdepth\dimen@i
  \fi
  \toks@\@xp{\shortauthors}\@temptokena\@xp{\shorttitle}%
  \edef\@tempa{\@nx\markboth{\the\toks@}{\the\@temptokena}}\@tempa
  \@setabstract
  \normalsize
  \if@titlepage
    \newpage
  \else
    \dimen@34\p@ \advance\dimen@-\baselineskip
    \vskip\dimen@\relax
  \fi
} % end \@maketitle
\renewcommand{\thanks}[1]{%
  \ifx\@empty\thankses
    \gdef\thankses{\thanks{#1}}%
  \else
    \g@addto@macro\thankses{\endgraf\thanks{#1}}%
  \fi}
\def\@setthanks{\def\thanks##1{\noindent##1\@addpunct.}\thankses}
\renewcommand{\curraddr}[2][]{%
  \ifx\@empty\addresses
    \gdef\addresses{\curraddr{#1}{#2}}%
  \else
    \g@addto@macro\addresses{\endgraf\curraddr{#1}{#2}}%
  \fi}
\renewcommand{\email}[2][]{%
  \ifx\@empty\addresses
    \gdef\addresses{\email{#1}{#2}}%
  \else
    \g@addto@macro\addresses{\endgraf\email{#1}{#2}}%
  \fi}
\renewcommand{\urladdr}[2][]{%
  \ifx\@empty\addresses
    \gdef\addresses{\urladdr{#1}{#2}}%
  \else
    \g@addto@macro\addresses{\endgraf\urladdr{#1}{#2}}%
  \fi}
\def\@setotheraddresses{%
  \def\curraddr##1##2{\noindent
    \emph{Current address\@ifnotempty{##1}{ of ##1}}:\space
      ##2\@addpunct.}%
  \def\email##1##2{\noindent
    \emph{E-mail address\@ifnotempty{##1}{ of ##1}}:\space
      \texttt{##2}}%
  \def\urladdr##1##2{\noindent
    \emph{WWW address\@ifnotempty{##1}{ of ##1}}:\space
      \texttt{##2}}%
  \addresses
}
\let\enddoc@text\relax
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\title[paper]{Nice paper}

\author{Me}
\address{University}
\email{mmm@lala.com}
\thanks{.}
\author{my friend}
\address{Institute}
\email{kkk@lala.edu}
\thanks{.}

\date{\today}
\keywords{XXX }

\begin{abstract}
Lalala
\end{abstract}

\maketitle

some text here.

\newpage

some text to force second page, to check running head

\end{document}
```

[image: output of example code]

Comment: O wow, that is a lot of code. :-)

Comment: @Johannes_B -- well, i said it wasn't trivial.  the ams document classes are very tightly controlled to make them conform to ams specs.  that means that changing the location of elements that are "locked in" to a particular place essentially means rewriting all the code that does the positioning in the first place.  the code could almost certainly be more compact, but i chose to start with something that existed, rather than undertaking a new approach that i knew would take more than an afternoon.

Comment: I really should take a closer look to the ams classes.