# how do i put address between author's name and abstract in amsart?

Tags: titles, amsart

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{graphicx}    %and others

\begin{document}

\title[short title]{Title}

%how to make the title^*

\author[Nguyen Thi Hong]{ Nguyen Thi Hong \textsuperscript{1**}}

\address{\textsuperscript{1}Faculty of Mathematics and Physics, Charles University. Prague, Czech Republic.}

\email{nguyenhonglove@gmail.com}

% i'd like to have the address placed here

\keywords{keyword1, keyword2, keyword3, ...}

\begin{abstract}
Abstract.....
\end{abstract}

\maketitle   %prints out Title, Author and Abstract (all in smallcaps)

%here is the contents, several pages of text 
%introduction, main part, conclusion
%in the first page, in footnotes I want to have before ** Email: nguyenhonglove@gmail.com

\begin{thebibliography}{99}
%references
\end{thebibliography}


\newpage
\begin{appendix}
%lots of figures
\end{appendix}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You don't HAVE to use \maketitle.

Comment: Related: [How to position the paper's authors' addresses on the front page (maketitle)?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/247515)

Comment: The linked question has an answer by now.

Comment: @Johannes_B: The linked question has a solution since yesterday, I posted one a week ago for this one, but I had not drawn much attention.

Answer (score 2):

The command `\maketitle` uses `\@maketitle` which contains the setting for authors etc and switches then more or less directly to the abstract. However, it's possible to use `\xpatchcmd` from the `xpatch` package and hook into `\@maketitle`, setting the addresses explicitly after the authors.

```
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{%
\@maketitle}{%
\ifx\@empty\authors \else \@setauthors \fi
}{%
  \ifx\@empty\authors \else \@setauthors \fi
  \ifx\@empty\addresses \else\@setaddresses\fi
}{\typeout{Patch successful}}{\typeout{Patch failed}}
\makeatother
```

I am unsure, whether a publisher will accept this.

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{%
\@maketitle}{%
\ifx\@empty\authors \else \@setauthors \fi
}{%
  \ifx\@empty\authors \else \@setauthors \fi

  \ifx\@empty\addresses \else\@setaddresses\fi
}{\typeout{Patch successful}}{\typeout{Patch failed}}
\makeatother

\usepackage{graphicx}    %and others

\begin{document}

\title[short title]{Title}

%how to make the title^*

\author[Nguyen Thi Hong]{ Nguyen Thi Hong \textsuperscript{1**}}

\address{\textsuperscript{1}Faculty of Mathematics and Physics, Charles University. Prague, Czech Republic.}

\email{nguyenhonglove@gmail.com}

% i'd like to have the address placed here

\keywords{keyword1, keyword2, keyword3, ...}

\begin{abstract}
Abstract.....
\end{abstract}

\maketitle   %prints out Title, Author and Abstract (all in smallcaps)

%here is the contents, several pages of text 
%introduction, main part, conclusion
%in the first page, in footnotes I want to have before ** Email: nguyenhonglove@gmail.com

\begin{thebibliography}{99}
%references
\end{thebibliography}


\newpage
\begin{appendix}
%lots of figures
\end{appendix}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I did not even notice that there was an answer here, sorry.